# Empty Cart on abandoned cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

Would it be possible to **automatically empty Magento cart** if someone abandoned the cart?
Basically we do not want customers to have **the previous cart items** stay in cart once they left the site or logout from the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to clear the cart at the time of logout. And for this you have to write a custom module that will have observe customer_logout event and execute the following code

```
<global>
    <events>
      <customer_logout> 
         <observers>
          <customer_logout_handler> 
            <type>model</type> 
            <class>modulename/observer</class> 
            <method>clearCartAtLogout</method>  
          </customer_logout_handler>
        </observers>
      </customer_logout>
    </events>
  </global>
```

`foreach(Mage::getSingleton("checkout/session")->getQuote()->getItemsCollection) as $item ){ 
Mage::getSingleton("checkout/cart")->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();
}`

And for guest user you can use this setting :
**Admin => system => Configuration => Sales => Checkout => Quote Lifetime (days)**

Comment: we already did created module for customers but there is no easy way for guest, If we define the quote lifetime (Days) , it will still keep the cart items for that many days in session, Even if we set the minimum 1 days , it will not clear the cat items immediately.

Comment: You have to create septate script/cron file and in that you have to load all the quote which are not converted in order and check the quote creation date. If that date is before 30* Min then you can delete that quote . 
Also set this file in cron to run every 30* Min. Or whatever time you want.